# What is the purpose of `candidate_count` argument used in `submit_candidacy` extrinsic

Tags: pallet-election-phragmen

The extrinsic uses the argument in the following lines of code:

```rust
let actual_count = <Candidates<T>>::decode_len().unwrap_or(0) as u32;
ensure!(actual_count <= candidate_count, Error::<T>::InvalidWitnessData);
ensure!(
    actual_count <= <T as Config>::MaxCandidates::get(),
    Error::<T>::TooManyCandidates
);
```

I am not sure I understand why would we provide the number of candidates as an argument if we are going to query the count of candidates in the extrinsic. What is the point of accepting possibly inaccurate information that doesn't seem to serve a purpose here?

There is probably a reason for this, but I don't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the weight formula:

```
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::submit_candidacy(*candidate_count))]
```

The `candidate_count` is an input to the formula and a requirement of weights is that they are "static" aka can be calculated before running the extrinsic. If you would read the candidate count as part of calculating the weight, the block producer would spent the resources to get the value from the state and then maybe rejecting the transaction for the current block because there isn't enough space anymore in the block. No one would pay the block producer for this operation. It would may open some attack vector against the chain, so the weight formulas are required to be static.